# Create/append file in Google cloud bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, append, google-cloud-storage

How do I create a file in my google cloud bucket, or append to the file if it already exists?

Let's say I want to add a file text.txt to my bucket, located at 'data_folder'. How do I check that it doesn't already exist?

Below does not work, at least for me.

```
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(data_folder, 'test.txt')):
        write_append()
    else:
        write_create()  # first run
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to append to an existing Cloud Storage file. As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/key-terms#immutability) (emphasis is mine):

> Objects are **immutable**, which means that an uploaded object cannot
>   change throughout its storage lifetime. An object's storage lifetime
>   is the time between successful object creation (upload) and successful
>   object deletion. In practice, this means that **you cannot make
>   incremental changes** to objects, **such as append operations** or truncate
>   operations.

You'll need  to manually check if the file exists and, if it does, get its content, append to it in your code and upload the new one.

Comment: Thank you @LundinCast ! I got an ok solution doing         with file_io.FileIO(data_folder + 'forecast.csv', mode='a+') as f:
            f.write(appended_data.to_csv(header=False, index=False))